# How to delete a file in Github with git command line?

Tags: git, github

I have a file 3 Mb large in Github, online only. I want to delete or move it, but Github won't let me do anything with it. It says 'This file has been truncated, but you can view the full file.' That is all. What can I do to move/delete it?

Comment: Could that be because the file is deleted on a previous commit? Or it can the be current state that the file is marked as deleted, and you just need to sync/push your current commit. Please show the output for "git status" command at your repository, how does it refer to the files you're trying to delete, are they still being tracked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: @mass Thank you! The status is: "Deleted: data2.txt" So it is not pushed. Now I see my mistake: I am not logged on in Git. How do I log in?

Comment: Are you on windows? AFAIK on osx and linux you get an automatic confirmation to get your public ssh key and then you forget about logging in when working from command line. Windows also has git shell but i recommend using github's client.

Comment: @mass I am on Linux. I am new with github. You have shown me the right way, when I printed "git status", I saw I had to go on to log in. How do I make your comment into an answer? :) Now it has synchronized. The problem is solved.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer and edited your tags. Im glad your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes all you need is a `git status` command.

Answer (score 0):

First, run `git clone <github url>`. Then change directories into that folder `cd <folder name>`. Run `git rm <filename>` to remove the file from the repository. If you want to move it, run `mv <filename> <folder to be moved to>`. After deleting run `git commit -m "<commit comment>"`. If you moved the file, run `git add <newfilename>` and then `git commit -m "<commit comment>"`. The commit comment should describe the changes you made (such as deleting the file). Then run `git push`, which will push your changes to Github.